# Travis CI - Push GitHub from dev to master branch

Tags: r, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have an R package in GitHub and I want to ensure that every commit in the master branch has successfully build on Travis CI.

So my though is to work exclusively on a "dev" branch and each time I commit, let Travis CI build and push to the master branch after success.

However, I'm the one not having any success.

I've tried multiple approaches ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925941/travis-ci-how-to-push-to-master-branch), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915499/push-to-git-master-branch-from-travis-ci), [this](https://gist.github.com/willprice/e07efd73fb7f13f917ea), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839883/pushing-on-a-git-repository-with-travis-ci) and [this](https://www.vinaygopinath.me/blog/tech/commit-to-master-branch-on-github-using-travis-ci/)) and all of them failed.

For more context, I also want Travis CI to deploy a jekyll-generated website to the gh-pages branch (which it currently does correctly if I push to master).

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Travis CI push to GitHub repo **gh-pages** branch based on commit changes on **master** branch. This is the reason why your jekyll-generated website able to push into gh-pages branch.

In your case, you want Travis CI push to GitHub repo **master** branch based on commit changes on **dev** branch.

This requires following Travis CI configurations in **.travis.yml**:

```
language: r
...
...
...
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  keep_history: true
  github_token: $github_token  # Your GitHub token set in Travis CI console
  target_branch: master        # Push into GitHub repo master branch
  on:
    branch: dev                # Your GitHub repo default branch
```